# How to get last N modified MongoDB documents?

Tags: mongodb

Each document has a **date** property which is updated with **new MongoDate()** whenever the document is modified.

How one can get N last modified documents? But not since some specific date. Just N documents with latest dates. Maybe something like *sort* only not as a cursor method, but a query parameter exists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a project I am working on, I use something like this to extract the last five entry, in reverse order (newest to older)

```
for e in coll.find().sort("data_ins", -1).limit(5):
    # do something
```

where data_ins is a timestamp, but I suppose it work on every sortable field.

Comment: Thanks. This will work for some time. But is it OK to get all your collection's documents into a cursor with large collections?

Comment: use explain http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain to check if mongo uses an index on data_ins. then it should be ok and fast to get N last entries.

Comment: @Vitaly: in my project I does not expect more than 100 or 150 documents, so it is a good solution, if you plan to use very large collection, you should use an index.

Comment: Another approach can be to have a separate collection where you save the N last modified documents, as a copy or a reference